# A finite group $G$ has two elements of the same order ; does there exists a group $H$ containing $G$ such that those elements are conjugate in $H$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group and $x,y \in G$ have the same order . Then is it true that there exists a group $H$ containing $G$ as a subgroup ( or an isomorphic copy) such that $x,y$ are conjugate in $H$ ? What I thought is to embed $G$ in $S_{|G|}$ , but the thing is can we show that the natural images of $x,y$ in $S_n$ ($n=|G|$ ) has same cycle structure ? If not , then is there any other way (is the claim true ?) ? Please help.

Comment: Your construction is the basis for Hall's universal countable locally finite group, as you can even replace $x,y$ by any finite isomorphic subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach works.  Say that $x$ and $y$ have order $d$.  Note that if $g\in G$, then the cycle of $g$ when $x$ acts on $G$ by translation has exactly $d$ elements, namely $g,xg,x^2g,\dots,x^{d-1}g$.  So all the cycles of the image of $x$ in $S_{|G|}$ have length $d$, and so the cycle structure of this image is just $|G|/d$ $d$-cycles.  The same is true of $y$, so the images of $x$ and $y$ in $S_{|G|}$ are conjugate.

(Note that the hypothesis that $G$ is finite is unnecessary.  This argument doesn't quite work if $G$ is countably infinite and $x$ and $y$ have infinite order, since you don't know that $x$ and $y$ must have the same number of cycles.  But you can fix this by first embedding $G$ in $G\times K$ for some infinite group $K$, to ensure $x$ and $y$ each have infinitely many cycles.)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are [HNN-extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension): introduced in a 1949 paper *Embedding Theorems for Groups* by Graham Higman, B. H. Neumann and Hanna Neumann, it embeds a given group $G$ into another group $H$, in such a way that two given isomorphic subgroups of $G$ are conjugate (through a given isomorphism) in $H$. Applied to your situation: $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$ are isomorphic.

Comment: But in the HNN-extension $G$ will not be finite and the question asks for a finite group $G$.

Comment: Derek, the overgroup is $H$, and I do not see any finiteness conditions on $H$....

Comment: Yes you are right, I midread the question. But it is a strange question, because there is not much point in assuming that $G$ is finite if you are not going to ask for $H$ to be finite.

Comment: anyway it works because $H$ is residually finite, so some finite quotient of $H$ (in which $G$ is mapped injectively) makes the job.